# The maximum area of a circle drawn between the graphs of $e^{-x²}$ and $-e^{-x²}$?

Tags: circles, error-function

**My question here is:** to calculate the surface of area of a max circle which we can draw between the two functions as shown in the below image 
 and also the surface of the area out this circle.

For the first question: I have calculated the integral $\int_{-1}^{1}2e^{-2x²}dx\,$ which is approximate to $2.395$ but i don't think that is true.

[image: Plots of bounding functions]

Comment: If you've already calculated that area then it is because you've already calculated *the circle*...right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1...try the following:

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be the point on the curve $y=e^{-x^2}$ where the normal to the curve passes through the origin.

Then the area of the circle is $\pi(x_0^2+y_0^2)$

Hint 2... To get the area enclosed between the curves and outside the circle, you can adapt the well known result $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac 12x^2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$$ to get the area between the curves and then...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about the surface of the area out of this circle ?

Comment: What do you mean by "surface area out of this circle"?

Comment: The external surface

Comment: The word "surface" refers to a three dimensional object, so I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: no, i meant 2-dimential, sorry i'm not familia with that

Comment: Do you mean the area enclosed between the curves but outside the circle?

Comment: yes exactly and thanks

Comment: See my edits...